# Sequelize: Update a column value on Model.destroy()

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a Model written in sequelize with `paranoid: true`, which means that upon `Model.destroy()`, the `deletedAt` column will have datetime value set.

However, I would like a custom column `is_archived` value set to 1 when `Model.destroy()` is called **without having to make a second Model.update() query after deletion**. 
I have tried setting `instance.is_archived = 1` inside `before/afterDestroy` hooks, but they do not seem to work.

Any suggestions :)?

Comment: Have you tried with beforeDestroy hook?

Comment: Yes, I can paste code if you would like

Comment: I tried, I think it is not possible. Better way is to use raw update query.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the verification =)

Answer (score 6):

Since there are no answers here, I'm posting this. Sequelize doesn't support updating properties inside `beforeDestroy` or `afterDestroy` hooks. The best way to do it is by calling `save()` or `update()` inside the hooks:

```
afterDestroy(instance) {
  instance.is_archived = 1;
  await instance.save({ paranoid: false, hooks: false });
}
```

It's better to do it inside `afterDestroy` as the deletion has already taken place. In `beforeDestroy` there is a chance the instance won't be deleted.

See https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9318.

Comment: You will run into `SequelizeDatabaseError: Lock wait timeout exceeded` doing this.

Comment: @FelipeWagner Sorry, would need to add `{ hooks: false }` inside the options. Updated the answer. Thanks for pointing out